# Windows 7 reset wireless password cache

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, networking

I have a wireless network WPA2-Enterprise (with login/password) and I want to delete the cached password and/or reset all the configs of wireless.

What's the file that caches that or the registry entry?

Windows 7, 64 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Vista and Windows 7 no longer store the Wireless keys in the registry.

Machine wide settings are stored at the following:

> c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\Interface Guid

Comment: Those files do not seem to contain any WPA2-Enterprise keys (those of networks using username/password combinations).

Answer (score 0):

For Vista I know, but I think windows 7 doesn't should be pretty the same.

- Click Start and select Network.
- Click the Network and Sharing Center button at the top of the window.
- Click Manage wireless networks.
- Right-click on NapAir and select Properties.
- Click the Security tab.
- Uncheck Cache user information for subsequent connections to this network.
- Click OK.